# Civilization VI does not show my graphics card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, steam

When I start Civilization VI it only lets me choose my on-board VGA controller, instead of my nVidia Geforce 940M.

```
lspci -vnn | grep 3D -A 12
```

shows

```
04:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940M] [10de:1347] (rev a2)
Subsystem: Lenovo GM108M [GeForce 940M] [17aa:5037]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 49
Memory at f1000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
I/O ports at 3000 [size=128]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_384_drm, nvidia_384
```

and `prime-select query` returns `nvidia`

Please Help!

Comment: If it runs it's using Nvidia. Steam says explicitly -> ***IMPORTANT NOTICE: ATI and INTEL chipsets are NOT supported to run Civilization VI LINUX***.

Comment: Totally not true....  Not supported means only 1 thing - nobody will try to help if you have an issue, not that the game wont work.